# apache2 - how to exclude alias from rewrite rules?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have setup mod_rewrite and mod_alias on Apache2 on Debian (in a test server).

I have the following rewrite code in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|html|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g)$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

I have the following alias code that is setup by default from the phpmyadmin package (loaded via `apt-get install phpmyadmin` and located in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`):

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Everytime I load http://my.test.server/phpmyadmin, it goes to http://my.test.server/index.php and not the alias (which is bypassed/ignored?).

How do I setup an exclusion rule to allow aliases to pass through (even if the alias is setup in a different file?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclude the URIs containing "/phpmyadmin/" if you don't want them redirected:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !/phpmyadmin/.*
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just move the declaration of your Alias before Directory or Location

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /var/(...)

<Location />
    RewriteEngine on
    # (...)
</Location>
```

By the wa: use Location with url ('/'), not 'Directory'.

Comment: The above advice to reorder Alias vs Rewrite does not work, regardless of the order of the conf file, Rewrite always happens before Alias.